# Drawable not showing or showing blurred on Galaxy 8+ or Note8

Tags: android, drawable

I've got problem with drawables in my app. I have different folders for different resolutions. Normally app works perfect however on new , big phones like Samsung galaxy S8+ , Note 8 images are not being displayed or they are blurred. I dont know if it's OS issue (both of them run with Oreo) or resolution problem ? What I know is that with previous OS and phones app works perfectly.

[image]

XML file for item :

```
<
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="145dp"
    android:background="@color/mainBrown"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:id="@+id/mission_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/missionTitle"
        android:text="Find 5 ATM's"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/missionPoints"
        android:text="10pt"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_coin"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/missionPoints"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your xml file

Comment: Added to post .

Comment: are you using all resolution?

Comment: @AnjalSaneen yes

Comment: xxxhdpi resolution also?

Comment: @AnjalSaneen yes